# Detecting locked tables (locked by LOCK TABLE)

Tags: mysql, locking

Is there a way to detect locked tables in MySQL? I mean tables locked by the `LOCK TABLE table WRITE/READ` command.

<sub>(Note that readers interested in detecting *named* locks acquired with `GET_LOCK` should read [Show all current locks from get_lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11034504/1709587) instead.)</sub>

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`SHOW OPEN TABLES` to show each table status and its lock.

For named locks see [Show all current locks from get_lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034504/show-all-current-locks-from-get-lock)

Comment: Answer simplified -> show open tables where `Database` = '[Table_Name]' and In_use > 0;

Answer (score 81):

Use `SHOW OPEN TABLES`:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-open-tables.html

You can do something like this

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE `Table` LIKE '%[TABLE_NAME]%' AND `Database` LIKE '[DBNAME]' AND In_use > 0;
```

to check any locked tables in a database.

Answer (score 47):

You can use `SHOW OPEN TABLES` to show each table's lock status. More details on the command's doc page are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-open-tables.html).

Answer (score 28):

The simplest way is :

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE In_use > 0
```

You get the locked tables only of the current database.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own lock with GET_LOCK(lockName,timeOut)

If you do a `GET_LOCK(lockName, 0)` with a 0 time out before you lock the tables and then follow that with a `RELEASE_LOCK(lockName)` then all other threads performing a `GET_LOCK()` will get a value of 0 which will tell them that the lock is being held by another thread.

However this won't work if you don't have all threads calling `GET_LOCK()` before locking tables. The documentation for locking tables is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: You can't for non named locks

Answer (score 3):

You could also get all relevant details from performance_schema:

```
SELECT
OBJECT_SCHEMA
,OBJECT_NAME
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTERNAL_LOCK)
FROM performance_schema.table_handles 
WHERE EXTERNAL_LOCK IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY
OBJECT_SCHEMA
,OBJECT_NAME
```

This works similar as

```
show open tables WHERE In_use > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The following answer was written by [Eric Leschinki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445131/eric-leschinski) in 2014/15 at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26743484/1709587 (now deleted):

> ### Mini walkthrough on how to detect locked tables:
>
> This may prevent the database from enforcing atomicity in the affected tables and rows.  The locks were designed to make sure things stay consistent and this procedure will prevent that process from taking place as designed.
>
> **Create your table, insert some rows**
>
> ```
> create table penguins(spam int, ham int);
> insert into penguins(spam, ham) values (3, 4);
> ```
>
> **show open tables:**
>
> ```
> show open tables like "penguins"
> ```
>
> prints:
>
> ```
> your_database penguins    0   0
> ```
>
> **Penguins isn't locked, lets lock it:**
>
> ```
> LOCK TABLES penguins READ;
> ```
>
> **Check if it's locked:**
>
> ```
> show open tables like "penguins"
> ```
>
> Prints:
>
> ```
> your_database, penguins 1, 0
> ```
>
> **Aha!  It is locked!  Lets unlock it:**
>
> ```
> unlock tables
> ```
>
> **Now it is unlocked:**
>
> ```
> show open tables like "penguins"
> ```
>
> Prints:
>
> ```
> your_database penguins    0   0
> ```
>
> ### show all current locks
>
> ```
> show open tables where in_use <> 0
> ```
>
> It would be much more helpful if the MySQL developers put this information in a regular table (so I can do a `select my_items from my_table where my_clauses`), rather than this stripped down 'show table' syntax from system variables.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314164438/http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/) describes how to get information about locked MySQL resources. `mysqladmin debug` might also be of some use.

Comment: Another example of why link-only answers are bad: this link is now dead, and so this answer is useless.

Comment: That was my plan, all those 13 years ago: that you'd see my answer yesterday and point out the broken link, so that I could come back with a triumphant "a-ha!" and say "another reason why the Internet Archive is a resource to be cherished and donated regularly to!" ;)

https://web.archive.org/web/20160314164438/http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/

Comment: Thanks for fixing it; however you should also edit your answer to add the relevant parts of the articles here. If someone were to read this answer while [offline](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/20/introducing-the-overflow-offline-project/), the Internet Archive wouldn’t help them.

Comment: "If someone accessed this on-line resource, but didn't have access to the Internet to access the Internet Archive..."...you can never do enough for some people.

Comment: Respecting the [basic rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Provide%20context%20for%20links) of the website is enough.