# How to detect a locked sql table in Qt?

Tags: qt, locking, innodb

I have a Qt application that freezes during a database query, because at the same time there is a SQL dump running in the background (it is happening during the nightly backup). The MySQL DB is an innoDB, that cannot be changed to MyISAM because of performance issues.

The pseudo code for the db connection is this, followed by the locking function `query.exec()`:

```
QSqlDatabase _db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QT_DB_TYPE, _con);

_db.setConnectOptions("MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT=1;");
_db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
_db.setDatabaseName("qtapp_db");
_db.setUserName("qtuser");
_db.setPassword("xxx");
_db.setPort("90000");
bool ok = _db.open();

qDebug() << "DBG: ############# db status: isopen()"<< _db.isOpen() << ", is valid; " << _db.isValid();

QSqlQuery query(_db);
query.prepare("INSERT huge_table {...}");

query.exec()
```

I would like to detect, if the table huge_table is locked, before I execute the INSERT. But `_db.isValid()` and `_db.isOpen()` returns true (anyway I should check this on the table itself, not the db, I think).

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [detecting locked tables mysql (locked by LOCK TABLE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499976/detecting-locked-tables-mysql-locked-by-lock-table)