# MySQL Join query incredibly slow, explain not helping

Tags: mysql, join

**QUERY**

```
explain select item_name, rating
from loyalty_visit_items
join loyalty_visits
on loyalty_visits.id = loyalty_visit_items.loyalty_visit_id
where loyalty_visits.parent_venue_id = 3794
```

**RESULTS**

```
1   SIMPLE  loyalty_visits       ref  PRIMARY,parent_venue_id  parent_venue_id   4  const                      14388    
1   SIMPLE  loyalty_visit_items  ref  loyalty_visit_id         loyalty_visit_id  5  loyalty.loyalty_visits.id  12     Using where
```

Indexes seem to be used properly, yet this query usually never returns before a timeout. There is very little data in this database relative to what it needs to scale to handle so I'm wondering what is up. I just want this to items and display a column from the parent visits table along with each item row. Is there a much better way to do this join that I am completely missing?

```
**CREATE SHOW TABLE**
CREATE TABLE `loyalty_visits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `loyalty_member_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `venue_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_venue_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visit_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_number` double(11,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spend` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` decimal(11,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms_from_number` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `server_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `server_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `terminal_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `initial_text_sent` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `error` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `visit_date` (`visit_date`),
  KEY `parent_venue_id` (`parent_venue_id`),
  KEY `idx2` (`code`) USING HASH,
  KEY `venue_id_2` (`venue_id`),
  KEY `rating` (`rating`),
  KEY `idx3` (`loyalty_member_id`) USING HASH,
  KEY `spend` (`spend`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`parent_venue_id`)
) ENGINE=Xeround DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499976/detecting-locked-tables-mysql-locked-by-lock-table

Comment: Let's see some `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output, please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that indexes are being used to maximum effect.  A join type of `ref` is not that great. `eq_ref` and `const` are much better.

You can see in the `rows` column that MySQL expects to read a large number of rows from `loyalty_visits`.  But since it's not finding rows by primary key, it can't use the clustered index.  This means MySQL probably has to perform many disk reads, so the index hardly helps.

How can this be optimized -- can you cut down the number of rows that need to be read?  Can you use a clustered index?  Can you use a covering index?

Comment: Created a clustered index for the two fields that are being pulled from loyalty_visits (id and parent_venue_id) but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: @Karl if you're using InnoDB, the primary key is the *only* clustered index possible.  You can't create new clustered indexes.  My point was that you should try to get your query to use the primary key if possible.

Comment: Perhaps this is just the case of me hitting my sql knowledge limit, but it is joining based on the primary key (id).

Comment: @Karl yes, but it's filtering based on `parent_venue_id`.  And that's the problem, because apparently that filter condition allows ~14k rows to pass through.  Rows that can not be quickly, sequentially accessed.  You can see in the explain results that MySQL considered using the primary key, but decided not to.

Comment: I had incorrectly assumed having that filter would limit the rows needing to be scanned. What would be the proper way to limit my result_set to rows with that parent_venue_id value? It is an indexed column.

Comment: Removing that filter returns the query in about 20 seconds. Obviously still something wrong with my query or indexes..

Comment: @Karl just because fewer rows need to be read, doesn't mean it's faster.  Details such as actual location of each of the rows on the hard disk matter.