# Show all current locks from get_lock

Tags: mysql, locking

Is there any way to select / show all current locks that have been taken out using the [`GET_LOCK` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock)?

Note that `GET_LOCK` locks are different from table locks, like those acquired with `LOCK TABLES` - readers who want to know how to see *those* locks should read [Detecting locked tables (locked by LOCK TABLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2499976/1709587)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From MySQL 5.7 onwards, this is possible, but requires first enabling the `mdl` instrument in the [`performance_schema.setup_instruments`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/setup-instruments-table.html) table. You can do this temporarily (until the server is next restarted) by running:

```
UPDATE performance_schema.setup_instruments
SET enabled = 'YES'
WHERE name = 'wait/lock/metadata/sql/mdl';
```

Or permanently, by adding the following incantation to the `[mysqld]` section of your `my.cnf` file (or whatever config files MySQL reads from on your installation):

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema_instrument = 'wait/lock/metadata/sql/mdl=ON'
```

(Naturally, MySQL will need to be restarted to make the config change take effect if you take the latter approach.)

Locks you take out *after* the `mdl` instrument has been enabled can be seen by running a `SELECT` against the [`performance_schema.metadata_locks`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/metadata-locks-table.html) table. As noted in the docs, `GET_LOCK` locks have an `OBJECT_TYPE` of `'USER LEVEL LOCK'`, so we can filter our query down to them with a `WHERE` clause:

```
mysql> SELECT GET_LOCK('foobarbaz', -1);
+---------------------------+
| GET_LOCK('foobarbaz', -1) |
+---------------------------+
|                         1 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.metadata_locks 
    -> WHERE OBJECT_TYPE='USER LEVEL LOCK'
    -> \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          OBJECT_TYPE: USER LEVEL LOCK
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: NULL
          OBJECT_NAME: foobarbaz
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 139872119610944
            LOCK_TYPE: EXCLUSIVE
        LOCK_DURATION: EXPLICIT
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
               SOURCE: item_func.cc:5482
      OWNER_THREAD_ID: 35
       OWNER_EVENT_ID: 3
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The meanings of the columns in this result are mostly adequately documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/metadata-locks-table.html, but one point of confusion is worth noting: the `OWNER_THREAD_ID` column does *not* contain the *connection* ID (like would be shown in the `PROCESSLIST` or returned by `CONNECTION_ID()`) of the thread that holds the lock. Confusingly, the term "thread ID" is sometimes used as a synonym of "connection ID" in the MySQL documentation, but this is *not* one of those times. If you want to determine the *connection* ID of the connection that holds a lock (for instance, in order to kill that connection with [`KILL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/kill.html)), you'll need to look up the `PROCESSLIST_ID` that corresponds to the `THREAD_ID` in the [`performance_schema.threads`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/threads-table.html) table. For instance, to kill the connection that was holding my lock above...

```
mysql> SELECT OWNER_THREAD_ID FROM performance_schema.metadata_locks
    -> WHERE OBJECT_TYPE='USER LEVEL LOCK'
    -> AND OBJECT_NAME='foobarbaz';
+-----------------+
| OWNER_THREAD_ID |
+-----------------+
|              35 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT PROCESSLIST_ID FROM performance_schema.threads
    -> WHERE THREAD_ID=35;
+----------------+
| PROCESSLIST_ID |
+----------------+
|             10 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> KILL 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1. Nice writeup, all is correct here. About THREAD_ID versus PROCESSLIST_ID, this is indeed an area causing confusion, which has historical roots with SHOW PROCESSLIST.

Answer (score 22):

Starting with MySQL 5.7, the performance schema exposes all metadata locks, including locks related to the `GET_LOCK()` function.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/metadata-locks-table.html

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question.  The capability does not apprear to exist in versions prior to 5.7.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, but holy cow it took me a *lot* of work to figure out how to get that table to actually contain anything or to make sense of its contents once I had. To save others the same struggle, I've [written up my findings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42356351/1709587) in my own answer here.

Comment: IIRC disabling `performance_schema` is best practice for production databases. Not sure how locks relate to performance stats anyway...  More recent versions of mariadb deal with this in a bit more sane way: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-metadata_lock_info-table/

Answer (score 11):

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

You will see the locks in there

Comment: The OP is asking about application locks, and this doesn't show those.

Comment: Please updated your answer on how to see locks with this command. As far as I it will only show you the currently executed commands, not the tables affected by locks.

Comment: @ooxi at `State` will be as `waiting for table metadata lock` for MyISAM; row level locks for InnoDB are checked with `Show Engine InnoDB Status`

Comment: Actually this allows to see which queries are waiting because of a table locked. So in some situations, this can be used to debug and see where the lock/problem is.

Comment: @peterh As stated in Toto's comment this is a valid answer for debugging purposes, but it should be downvoted indeed.

Comment: -1 because this isn't an answer to the question asked. `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` may show table/row locks as noted by @danielpopa, but doesn't show `GET_LOCK` locks.

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to determine whether a *particular* named lock is currently held, you can use [`IS_USED_LOCK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-used-lock):

```
SELECT IS_USED_LOCK('foobar');
```

If some connection holds the lock, that connection's ID will be returned; otherwise, the result is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

**[Reference taken from this post:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/02/mysql-script-to-identify-the-locks-and-blocking-transactions/)**

You can also use this script to find lock in MySQL.

```
SELECT 
    pl.id
    ,pl.user
    ,pl.state
    ,it.trx_id 
    ,it.trx_mysql_thread_id 
    ,it.trx_query AS query
    ,it.trx_id AS blocking_trx_id
    ,it.trx_mysql_thread_id AS blocking_thread
    ,it.trx_query AS blocking_query
FROM information_schema.processlist AS pl 
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx AS it
    ON pl.id = it.trx_mysql_thread_id
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_lock_waits AS ilw
    ON it.trx_id = ilw.requesting_trx_id 
        AND it.trx_id = ilw.blocking_trx_id
```

Comment: -1; this is a mechanism for finding *table* locks, not *named* locks, and therefore irrelevant to the question, plus it uses a deprecated table - if you run this on a recent MySQL release and run `SHOW WARNINGS` afterwards you'll see `'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.`

Answer (score 1):

I found following way which can be used if you KNOW name of lock

```
select IS_USED_LOCK('lockname');
```

however i not found any info about how to list all names.

Comment: This is useful because it can be used to get the meta information about who has the lock and kill the query if necessary.

Comment: @arheops any reason why you chose to roll back my addition of a docs link and information about what `IS_USED_LOCK` returns? It seems to me that this answer is less useful without that information; your way, I have to Google the function name find the docs, and read in the docs what it returns in order to be able to actually use this answer, rather than the information being there in front of me.

Comment: After change it no more say what it say now. You are free create your own answer.

Answer (score -2):

Another easy way is to use:

```
mysqladmin debug
```

This dumps a lot of information (including locks) to the error log.

Comment: -1; I just tested on MySQL 5.7 by taking out a named lock in one terminal and then calling `mysqladmin` from another. The information dumped into my error log did not contain any reference whatsoever to the lock I'd taken out.

Comment: too generic answer, that does not help