# Error while mysql table gets updated from java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to update one particular record in mysql table from java code. Update function doing lots of different activities including the update operation within the same transaction.

But here the same table row is not getting updated from outside (MySQL Workbench) or other transaction until the transaction for update gets committed. Its generating the following error.

**Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction**

Is there any work around to fix the issue? Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried removing all the other code from the Update function to see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Smith thanks for your reply. Yes I have checked the same. Problem still exists.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034504/show-all-current-locks-from-get-lock