# Fast raising number of sleeping MySQL connections on AWS RDS when calling in parallel from web server API

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, amazon-rds, aspnetboilerplate, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am using aspnetboilerplate core and entityframework core.

I have 1 request entity framework core which is big:

```
var user = _userRepository.GetAll()
            .Include(u => u.FavoriteMeals).ThenInclude(c => c.Category)
            .Include(u => u.FavoriteRestaurants).ThenInclude(c => c.CategoryMaster)
            .Include(u => u.FavoriteSpecialityMeals).ThenInclude(c => c.Speciality)
            .Include(u => u.FavoriteSuperBookings).ThenInclude(c => c.Boooking)
            .Include(u => u.FavouritePlaces).ThenInclude(c => c.Place)
            .Include(u => u.Followers).ThenInclude(u => u.User1)
            .Include(u => u.Followings).ThenInclude(u => u.User2)
            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
```

I use AWS RDS MySQL. And I can see that the number of connections to the database is raising to 58 when I call the API through swagger.

Then I would like to know:

Is it normal to have arround 60 connections to the database? Then I plan to use this api connected to a mobile app.

The limit of max connections on aws is per mobile or global. I mean if two mobiles are connected to my api and calls the same api function are they gonna be blocked because the number of max connections was reached?

How can I optimize this?

Thanks,

///// EDIT

I have discovered that I have a lot of requests which are kept in slepp state.

How can I fix this? My code is a s below:

```
builder.UseMySql(connectionString);
        //todo
        builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
        builder.EnableDetailedErrors(true);
```

Please find below my requests result to find the sleep state

[image]

Comment: one user causes 58 connections? redesign your app

Comment: Ok I found some more clues. MySql keeps 1 connection and a lot of requests are in sleeping state and stays in threads.I see this here: select id,
       user,
       host,
       db,
       command,
       time,
       state,
       info
from information_schema.processlist; They are not killed. What am I missing?

Comment: check if you have some locks

Comment: How can I see this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034504/show-all-current-locks-from-get-lock

Comment: I tried the request show open tables where In_Use > 0 ; and nothing appears.

Comment: see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/thread-information.html  and check if they have still open and for how long

Answer (score 2):

The reason many connections are open with a sleep status is, that by default, [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) which is used by Pomelo, has connection pooling enabled (`Pooling=true`), with a max. of 100 connections per connection string (`MaxPoolSize=100`). See [MySQL .NET Connection String Options](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/) for all default settings.

So having around 60 connections opened can easily happen, when either 60 people use the app API in parallel, or e.g. when 3 different connection strings are used, each with 20 users in parallel.

Once those connections have been opened, they will effectively stay open for a long time by default.

With `ConnectionLifeTime=0` as the default setting, they will never be explicitly closed by MySqlConnector's connection pooling management. However, they will always be closed after a number of seconds specified by the MySQL system variable [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout). But since this variable is set to `28800` by default, it will take 8 hours before once created pooled connections are being closed by MySQL (independent of how long they were in a sleep state).

So, to lower the number of parallel connections, either disable `Pooling` (radical method with some performance implications if the server is not hosted locally) or manage their lifetime through the `MaxPoolSize` and `ConnectionLifeTime` connection string parameters.

---

In the screenshot you provided, you can see that the host varies in its address and port, but these are the address and outgoing port of the connecting client.

However, what I have written above does also apply here. So if you are connecting from multiple web servers (clients from the viewpoint of MySQL) to your database server, by default, each web server will manage its own connection pool and keep up to 100 connections open.

For example, if you have a load balancer setup, and multiple web servers behind it that may each execute database queries, or you run your API with some server-less technology like AWS Lambda, where your API might be hosted on many different web servers, then you might end up with multiple connection pools (one for each connection string on each web server).

---

> My issue is that is only for one user connected. I am using `Task.WhenAll()` in my app which launches several api requests in parallel and I also use asynchronous methods in my api which creates some new threads.

If your client sends multiple web request (e.g. REST) to your API hosted on multiple web servers/AWS Lambda, then MySQL will at least need that many connections opened at the same time.

The MySqlConnector connection pooling will keep those connections open by default, after they were used (up until 100 connections per web server).

You will end up with the following number of sleeping database connections (assuming the connection string always stays the same on each web server):

```
number-of-parallel-requests-per-client * number-of-clients * number-of-webservers
```

However, the max. number of connections kept open will (by default) not be higher than:

```
number-of-webservers * 100
```

So if your app executes 20 requests in parallel, with each of them establishing a database connection from the API (web server) to the database server, then depending on your API hosting scenario, the following will happen:

- **3 Web Servers with Load Balancer:** If you run your app often enough, the load balancer will distribute your requests to all 3 web servers over time. So each of the 3 web servers will keep around 20 connections open to your database server. You end up with 60 connections, as long as only one client executes these requests at the same time. If a max. of 4 clients run 20 requests in parallel, you will end up with 80 connections being kept open per web server over time, so a total of 3 * 80 = 240 total sleeping database connections.
- **Serverless technology like AWS Lambda:** The same as in the previous example applies to AWS Lambda, but the number of web servers is infinite (in theory). So your might end up exceeding MySQL's [max_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) setting pretty fast, if AWS decides to distribute the API calls to many different web servers.

---

#### Advice how to configure connection pooling

If you run your API on a fixed number of web servers, you might want to keep `Pooling=true` and set `MaxPoolSize` to a values, that `number-of-parallel-requests-per-client * number-of-webservers` will always be lower than [max_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections), but if possible higher than `typical-number-of-parallel-clients * number-of-parallel-requests-per-client`. If that is not plausible or possible, consider setting `Pooling=false` or set `MaxPoolSize` to a number not higher than `max_connections / number-of-webservers`.

If you run your API on a serverless technology like AWS Lambda, either set `Pooling=false` or set `MaxPoolSize` to some low value and `ConnectionLifeTime` to some low value greater than zero. I would just set `Pooling=false`, because it is way easier to disable connection pooling than to effectively fine tune connection pooling for a serverless environment.

Comment: Thanks for the détails. My issue is that is only for one user connected.  I am using task.whenall in my app which launches several api requests in parallel and I also use asynchronous methods in my api which creates some new threads. What I'd not understand is why the connection changes with different port and host for each threads? My connectionstring does not change and only one user is connected.

Comment: So host and port are actually the client address and port, and not the one of your MySQL server, so they are not a general issue here. Though of course, if you run connections from different clients each client will manage its own connection pool. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I also extended the answer with two typical scenarios and gave some concrete configuration advice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and details. I use AWS lambda. Then I will disable pooling. And try. I hope I will not have performance issues.

Comment: I found this which expalins the issue and provide an aws solution https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: Using a database proxy for AWS Lambda should be a good choice. However, you will probably need to disable connection pooling in the connection string here as well, if the proxy manages its own pool of connections.