# How to check a table is being accessed(not updated) from user request (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to check if a particular **table (not db)** is currently being accessed(active) through any user request.
Assuming I have admin privilege.

Comment: if the goal is to prevent concurrent updates, maybe you can give a try with `LOCK TABLE` and `SHOW OPEN TABLES`, or named locks, as suggested [in this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499976/detecting-locked-tables-locked-by-lock-table) (never tried myself)

Comment: With `show processlist;` you can show all requests running at the moment you execute this command. The result could be parsed to get the accessed tables. But the most SELECT statements are too quick to get caught by this method at a given point of time. So its more or less useless for short running statements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible directly using MySQL. What I could think is, you can have a B-Layer, and log / restrict / control the access to information. Think of it as like an Access Control list? That'd be the best way.